# XMPP service-unavailable(503) error during UserSearchManager

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, smack, asmack

This morning i have involved with a complex problem. 
I am creating chat application using XMPP. I have success to login and can chat with user.

Now, I want to **search user** in XMPP server. But i got error **service-unavailable(503)**

This is my code:-

```
 UserSearchManager usm = new UserSearchManager(connection);
Form searchForm = usm.getSearchForm("search."+connection.getServiceName());
Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm();
answerForm.setAnswer("Username", true);
answerForm.setAnswer("search", "rahul@opensip01");
ReportedData data = usm.getSearchResults(answerForm, "search."+connection.getServiceName());
System.out.println("data is "+data);
```

One more point. When i use to **getSearchServices()** by visit http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/3.2.2/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/search/UserSearchManager.html#getSearchServices() . i got **zero** value.

this was code:-

```
UserSearchManager usm = new UserSearchManager(connection);
System.out.println(usm.getSearchServices().size());
```

I have install Advance search plugin in my XMPP server. but still got zero output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When serach don't use `@` just type name like this

`answerForm.setAnswer("search", "rahul");`

Comment: I tied your code. It is worked for me. Are you add provider to your code and any version used?

Comment: Sry i didnt get. This is my connection code. ** String host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
          String port = "5222";
          String service = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
          String username = "xxx";
          String password = "xxx";ConnectionConfiguration connConfig=new ConnectionConfiguration(host, Integer.parseInt(port),service); connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig); connection.connect(); connection.login(username, password); Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);                connection.sendPacket(presence);**

Comment: I installed advance search plugin in my xmpp server.

Comment: Try add this `SmackAndroid.init(context);` before `connection.connect();`.

Comment: this package import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackAndroid; is not found. do i need to change my jar file

Comment: I used this [https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack) and you can download jar file from this link [asmack.0.8.2](http://asmack.freakempire.de/0.8.2/).

Comment: i am also facing same problem and above solutions didn't work for me. i am using same lib but of different version it is asmack-android-8.0.8.10. So is it related to library version ?